# Sätze mit "dass" am Anfang, die Bitte, Drohung usw. ausdrücken

Tags: difference

Wodurch unterscheiden sich die folgenden zwei Sätze?

> Behalte deinen Vater im Auge!
>
> Dass du deinen Vater im Auge behältst!

Comment: Durch die Zahl der Wörter? Durch die Stellung des Verbs im Satz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beide Aufforderungen bedeuten das Gleiche, die zweite ist lediglich etwas nachdrücklicher und wird auch gern mit *»mir ja/bloß«* ergänzt.

> Dass du **mir ja** deinen Vater im Auge behältst!

Oder auch so:

> **Sieh zu**, dass du deinen Vater im Auge behältst!

Man kann sagen, dass dein zweiter Satz die Kurzform des Satzes mit *»Sieh zu«* ist.

Answer (score 2):

Nur das erste Beispiel ist ein vollständiger Satz. Das zweite taugt eher umgangssprachlich, und ist in sofern mehrdeutig, als der Hauptsatz fehlt, der lauten könnte

- Ich rate dir,
- Ich empfehle dir dringend,
- Ich bitte dich,
- Achte darauf,

Trotz der Vermeidung des Imperativs macht diese Variante einen unfreundlicheren, genervteren Eindruck.